# Output is different than I expected

Tags: python

I have created a shopping list for different fruits, and the output should be "not done" because it is false according to the statement:

```
shopping_cart = ['apples', 'oranges', 'banana', 'kiwi', 'avocado', 'peaches']
s_list = list(shopping_cart)
for mango in s_list:
    if mango in shopping_cart:
        print('Done')
    else:
        print('not done')
```

No error.

Comment: You do not need any loops here just `"mango" in shopping_cart:`

Comment: `msg = "Done" if "mango" in shopping_cart else "not done"; print(msg)`? `shopping_cart` is already a `list`.

Comment: Why are you casting a list to list? and what is `mango`? did you mean `"mango"`?

Answer (score 2):

```
shopping_cart = ['apples', 'oranges', 'banana', 'kiwi', 'avocado', 'peaches']
s_list = list(shopping_cart) # shopping_cart is already list so you can ignore it. 
if 'mango' in s_list:
    print('Done')
else:
    print('Not Done')
```

Answer (score 2):

i Think this is what you're trying to do:

```
shopping_cart = ['apples', 'oranges', 'banana', 'kiwi', 'avocado', 'peaches']
if 'mango' in shopping_cart:
    print('Done')
else:
    print('Not done')
```

In your code, you're looping through the shopping cart list and checking if that item (which it is of course) so it will just print a bunch of 'Done'

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you have a misunderstanding with how the code works.
`for mango in s_list` creates a placeholder variable named mango, which is then assigned the value of each item in `s_list` over the iterations. Since the item which is currently the value of `mango` is always in the list, this part `if mango in shopping_cart` always evaluates as true.
This code will check each item if it's a mango:

```
shopping_cart = ['apples', 'oranges', 'banana', 'kiwi', 'avocado', 'peaches']
s_list = list(shopping_cart)

for item in s_list:
    if item == 'mango':
        print('Done')
    else:
        print('Not done')
```

If you just want to know if there's a mango in the cart, you can just skip the loop and do it like this:

```
if 'mango' in shopping_cart:
    print('Done')
else:
    print('Not done')
```

Comment: Or if you don't want to repeat `not done`, you can simply add `break` inside of the `else` statement.

Comment: @miador yup. Alternatively, set a bool flag and only operate on that during the loop, then print `done` or `not done` after the loop depending on the state of that flag.

Comment: oh! so you are saying that loop is creating a value named mango and when iterates over the list it makes each value as mango and that is why it is returning as True

Comment: Thanks@NightDice mate. Really appreciate it

Comment: @PrabhneetSingh Exactly that. I hope you understand why it didn't work now :)